# Mono on Linux: mkbundle does not find shared libraries

Tags: c#, mono, dependencies, shared-libraries, mkbundle

I have a small C# application that I want to turn into a native executable binary.
`csc Foo.cs` runs without warnings and I can run the application without problems as such: `mono Foo.exe`.

When I start mkbundle however, I get this error:

```
$ mkbundle Foo.exe
Failure to load i18n assemblies, the following directories were searched for the assemblies:
Path: .
In Custom mode, you need to provide the directory to lookup assemblies from using -L
ERROR: Couldn't load one or more of the i18n assemblies: Failed to load I18N.dll
```

I found various versions of the I18N.dll at `/usr/lib/mono/...` and after passing the parent directory of one of them to `mkbundle` by using `-L`, it all worked.

But why do I have to do that? The `-L` option is not used in any of the examples I found online.

Am I in "Custom mode"? And if so, what is custom mode?
I rather expect this to be a problem with a missing environment variable, but I don't know what I have to change.

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

if your assembly doesn't make use of internationalization (i18n) try mkbundle --i18n none